# Suggestion for new tag: toml (or structured-document-format)

Tags: discussion, tags

I wonder if there is room for a new tag that could be applied to question relating to TOML ([Tom's Obvious Minimal Language](https://toml.io/en/)), a structured document format similar to YAML and JSON, mainly used for configuration files.

TOML typically looks similar to what some people would call "INI files" (there is to my knowledge no tag for "INI files", and I don't think one is desperately needed):

```
[location]
source_directories = [ "/home", "/etc", "/var/log/syslog*",]
repositories = [ "user@backupserver:sourcehostname.borg",]

[retention]
keep_daily = 7
```

There are command line parsers for TOML (e.g. [`tomlq`](https://kislyuk.github.io/yq/) and [`yj`](https://github.com/sclevine/yj)).

There are currently 17 hits for the search term "[toml](https://unix.stackexchange.com/search?q=toml)" on the main site.  This is not very many.

An alternative would possibly be to introduce a more generic "structured-document-format" tag.

My main concern is that questions relating to TOML (and to other minor structured document formats, e.g. [HCL](https://github.com/hashicorp/hcl)) ends up being tagged with [text-processing](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/text-processing), [sed](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sed), [awk](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/awk) and similar tags, even though there are obvious issues relating to the parsing or creation of such files by line-oriented tools, and even though there exists tools specifically designed for working with them.

Comment: +1 - because I've actually learnt something new today.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

We already have format-specific tags such as [yaml](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/yaml) and [json](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/json), so I think it would make sense to create [toml](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/toml).

One advantage I see to having a format-specific tag, rather than a generic tag for all structured document formats, is that it will separate the format-specific *tools* as well. Instead of having a lengthy catalog of formats and tools in a generic tag wiki, we can have detailed information in each format-specific tag wiki (even if few people read it...).

Comment: Since there was a generally positive response to the question, based on the upvotes, and since this answer was well received, I decided to create the [tag:toml] tag.  Thank you!